# How to fulfill the condition correctly "If" in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, ajax

```
            function UserCheckId() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "/Home/SomeAction",
                    data: { qrcode: scannedQR[txt] },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                            if (data = "Storekeeper") {
                                document.location.replace("/Storekeeper.aspx");
                            }
                            else {
                                alert("Error");
                            }
                    }
                });
```

There is a UserCheckId function in which I call the SomeAction function from C # (it returns a string value) and pass the result to Javascript. After that, I want to check what the value of the result is. If "Storekeeper", then go to the site, otherwise an error pops up. The problem is that whatever the value is (for example, C # will return the value "Collector"), the condition for the Storekeeper is met in any case. I checked data with alert, it outputs the string value correctly. What to do? Help me please!

Comment: I did not undertsand this line `. The problem is that whatever the value is (for example, C # will return the value "Collector"), the condition for the Storekeeper is met in any case.`

Comment: `=` is an assignment. for comparison use `==` or `===`. An assinment will always return the assigned value, an as this is nonempty string, inside the condition of an `if` it will evaluate to a truthy, thus the first branch of the if will be executed.

Comment: do `console.log(data)` see what it prints .

Comment: @Swati If you put it before the `if` it will print whatever value `data` had before the `if` . And if you put it after the `if`, it will print `Storekeeper` after the `if` because that's the value `data` gets assigned in the condition `if(data = "Storekeeper")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check equality in javascript use strict equality operator `===` which will check both type and value. Also always normalize (like trim, toLowerCase etc) before any comparison operation

```
if (data?.trim().toLowerCase() === "storekeeper") {
```

Comment: Not sure why you're using `toLowerCase`, he might not want to accept e.g. `"STOREKEEPER"`.

Comment: It's better to normalize before any comparison operation. Like trim, toLowerCase, so that any unwanted space or capital letter can be handled

Comment: No, it isn't "better". Sometimes it may be appropiate, sometimes not.

Comment: No no I appreciate your feedback, kindly keep this.

Comment: OP's problem (probably) doesn't have anything to do with casing of the values. The main problem is, he used an assignment (`=`) instead of a comparison (`==` or `===`). You should have mentioned that in your answer. Also *"always normalize ..."*  is not a valid assumption, because this may not be appropriate in all situations, where one wants to distinguish between `"Storekeeper"`, `"storekeeper"` and `"STOREKEEPER"`

Comment: How do you know it will be `==` or `===` instead of `=`? If `data` is a string contains `Storekeeper` in that case it should be `data.includes('Storekeeper'). Yours is also not a valid assumption.

Comment: How about adding `.normalize()` also, just for fun.

Comment: Yeah we should also add `localeCompare()` just for fun

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath because `=` is an assignment, which assigns the value `Storekeeper` to the varable `data`, which in 99,9% of the cases is an error if used in the condition of an `if` (especially if a hardcoded constant is assigned).  And the result of an assignment is always the assigned value (in this case `"Storekeeper"`). And OP's question was, why the condition always is hit, eventhough `data` was set to a differnt value before ...

Comment: @derpirscher `=` definitely should not be. But the assumption you are making about `==` and `===` may not be valid too as `data` can be an string contains the word or array or an object.

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath If you read the question carefully, *"[...] the problem is that whatever the value is (for example, C # will return the value "Collector") [...]"*  so it's quite safe to assume, that the intention is to check, whether the variable `data` has the value `"Storekeeper"` Of course, it might be, that `data` is an object or an array or whatever. But I'm a fan of Ockham's Razor and try to rule out obvious errors first and only jump to long-shot conclusions if the simple solutions don't work.

Comment: @derpirscher my answer is also very simplest only and I also started on a very simplest assumption and that's why I straight a way mentioned `===` and the basic normalization operation. If you had gone through the code properly, you would find it's redirecting to a url only and when it's url caps doesn't matter. So there might be values with caps or small caps, so to incorporate those cases on a simples note I added basic normalization operation. If that doesn't required, it can always be removed as those are not huge pile of codes.

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath Your answer is missing the basic point, ie WHY using `=` is an error. All other things ( `==` vs `===`, normalization, ...) you can mention as possibility to enhance your anwser. But *"Always normalize ... before any comparison"*  as a rule, is just plain wrong ...

Comment: @derpirscher lol it's definitely not missing the basic point. It's just a vague point yours. You should always keep in mind about normalization when comparing. Now if your usecases do not need normalization do not do or less normalization do less. But if you do not practice doing normalization then when you must apply normalization then you will miss that as you do not do normalization. So always do normalization when doing comparison. Ok.